# Disable game bar for a certain program

Tags: windows-10

A while ago, I used the game bar to record something in Chrome. Now, whenever I open Chrome, a dark rectangle shows up for a few seconds telling me to "Select [circle icon] to record your game".

How can I disable this popup without disabling the game bar completely?

Comment: While in the state you describe have you tried to open the "Game Bar" with `Windows Key+G`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. While Google Chrome is in the forefront, open the game bar (either by clicking on the popup when it appears or with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>).
2. Click the gear (⚙️) icon to open Game Bar settings.
3. Uncheck "Remember this as a game ☑️".